# What are the methods of proving that something is not an affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

To prove that something is an affine variety, we would find a polynomial. So for V(x-y), we would have the polynomial y=x and the variety would describe a line through the origin.

What are the methods of proving that something is not an affine variety? Are there any somewhat elementary methods?

Edit: Also, if the variety can be expressed by $V(p(x_1,...x_n))$ is that always going to be an affine variety?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea. Assume a polynomial (of a given minimal degree $n$) exists and prove a contradiction? How is your object that may-or-may-not be an affine variety defined?

Comment: A cursory inspection of Wikipedia suggests that affine varieties never have interesting cohomology. So if you can show that your arbitrary algebraic variety does have interesting cohomology, it's not affine. Unfortunately I don't think this works both ways; I think some non-affine varieties still have uninteresting cohomology by accident. I've forgotten all the algebraic geometry I used to know, though, so I'm done now.

Comment: In your edit, if $p$ is a polynomial, then of course $V(p)$ is an affine subvariety of $n$-dimensional space, unless you're using a restrictive definition of variety. Have you not had affine varieties *defined* as the zero sets of systems of polynomials in affine space?

Comment: As to your question itself, "something" is too vague. Are you thinking of being given a subset of affine space, or an abstract topological space, or (a scheme, or...) ?

Comment: Does an affine Variety have to be defined over a field? Or is an integral domain sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your background is in algebraic geometry, but Theorem III.3.7 of Hartshorne gives a criterion for a scheme to be affine (assuming you know scheme theory and cohomology).

Using only sheaf language, if $X$ is a noetherian scheme, then it is affine if and only if for every ideal sheaf $\mathscr{I}\subseteq\mathcal{O}_X$, the map
$$\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to\Gamma({X,\mathcal{O}}_X/\mathscr{I})$$
is surjective, where $\Gamma$ denotes the global section functor.

Comment: There is also Serre's Theorem on the vanishing of the higher cohomology of any quasi-coherent sheaf.

Comment: Dear @Benja, that is precisely Theorem III 3.7 of Hartshorne, which is equivalent to what I wrote above.